# Выполнение функции по перезагрузке iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Как сделать так, чтобы когда в `iframe` загружается новая страница, выполнялась функция?

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример

```
$('#iframeid').load(function(){
    alert('IFrame загрузился или перезагрузился)');
});
```